# NumPy - Random Seed not working when sample size changes?

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

Can anyone help me understand why the following code will not keep random_list_2 the same when I change the sample size, say from 3000 to 5000?

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2)
sample_size = 3000

random_list_1 = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 3, size = sample_size).tolist()
random_list_2 = np.random.randint(low = 100000, high = 1000000000, size = sample_size).tolist()
```

Comment: I'm confused what you're expecting, are you expecting the first 3000 values of `random_list_2` to be the same when its sample size is 5000?

Comment: @Moosefeather yes, precisely. I believe Prune answered my question with his example of giving a new seed before generating another random list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seed is only the starting value for the RNG (Random Number Generator).  Each random number you generate updates the seed.  When you specify a starting seed, then you get a deterministic, reproducible sequence of seed values.

When you change the sample size, you change the quantity of updates in the `randint` call.  Where the second call used to start at value 3001 in this sequence, it now starts at 5001.

```
random_list_1 = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 3, size = sample_size).tolist()
random_list_2 = np.random.randint(low = 100000, high = 1000000000, size = sample_size).tolist()
```

If you were to replace `sample_size` with 1000, you would see that the those 1000 random integers are the same ones you got with the last 1000 numbers of the original (size 3000) call.  In this case, you will get those 1000, and another 4000 new integers.

If you want to maintain `random_list_2`, then you need to give it a stable seed of its own: either give it a separate seed, or switch the call order.  Switching the order would simply transfer the same effect to `random_list_1`.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this. I did not understand that this was occurring! This solved my problem.